# How to convert "datetime" to "varchar" without seconds?

Tags: sql-server

My SQL code:

```
declare @date datetime
declare @str varchar(4000)

set @date = '2014-11-25 19:00'
set @str = convert(varchar, @date, 120)

select @str
```

The result looks as following:

```
2014-11-25 19:00:00
```

How to get it without seconds?

Comment: You've marked an answer that removes the time altogether and just shows the date. Is that what you were after? If so, please edit your question to make that clear as the other answers are better solutions to the question as it's posted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
declare @date datetime
declare @str varchar(4000)

set @date = '2014-11-25 19:00'
set @str = convert(varchar, @date, 101)

or

set @str =  Convert(varchar(10), CONVERT(date, @date))
```

Comment: I don't see how this is the correct answer as it doesn't include the time at all. OP is asking to remove seconds not the time completely.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using a date format with predictable length, you can just specify the length of the `varchar` type:

```
set @str = convert(varchar(16), @date, 120)
```

Comment: Although the rest are also valid solutions, this is the nicest!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.... (just needed to crop the string)

```
declare @date datetime = '2014-11-25 19:00'
declare @str varchar(4000)
set @str = convert(varchar, @date, 120)

select SUBSTRING(@str, 1, 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're converting it to a `varchar`, you can simply remove the last 3 characters (or take the first 16), as a `datetime` in the format you have specified (`120`) will always have 19 characters:

```
declare @date datetime
declare @str varchar(4000)

set @date = '2014-11-25 19:00'
set @str = LEFT(convert(varchar, @date, 120),16)

select @str
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use `Substring` function from 1 to 16 chars

```
declare @date datetime
declare @str varchar(4000)

set @date = '2014-11-25 19:00'
set @str = SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, @date, 120),1,16)

select @str

OUTPUT
2014-11-25 19:00
```